# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'embed' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

And so, when creating your bot on `Discord.py` - not knowing python itself.  I got an error when executing the command `.hug`

```py
@commands.command(name="hug")
async def hug(self, ctx):

    hugs = [('https://tenor.com/view/anime-neko-k-on-hug-friends-gif-13124779'), 
        ('https://tenor.com/view/anime-hug-love-smile-gif-15942846'), 
        ('https://tenor.com/view/toilet-bound-hanakokun-anime-anime-hug-gif-16831471'), ('https://tenor.com/view/neko-anime-hug-gif-10989534')]
        
    hugsrandom = random.choice(hugs)
    embed=embed.set_image(hugsrandom)
    discord.Embed(title="**Вы обняли@{}** ".format(ctx.message.author.id))
        
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

It means that the line of code:

```py
embed=embed.set_image(hugsrandom)
```

references the variable embed before it gets assigned. Basically the left side of the argument gets called but there is no embed variable yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because you are using an undefined variable to define itself.

```
embed=embed.set_image(hugsrandom)
```

You're looking for a method `set_image()` to exist for an object `embed`, but `embed` does not yet exist. It's like the "chicken and the egg" problem. Normally you can use a variable to change its own value, but the variable on the right-hand side must be defined before you can use it. Here, you are trying to use `embed` before it's been defined.